# Как читать данные с firebase, если используется цикл for

Tags: java, android, firebase, for

Всем привет, у меня есть проблема. Я не знаю как прочитать данные с firebase если используется цикл.
Вот основной код:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wods);
    init();
    mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("workouts");
    mDataBase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot da : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Workout workout =  da.getValue(Workout.class);
                listA.add(workout);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}

public void init(){
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listA = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, listA);
}
```

}

Код в папке Workout

```
public class Workout {
String name;
String MG;
String male;
String num1;
String num2;
String num3;
String t;
String time;

public List<Note> workout2 = new ArrayList<>();
public Workout() {
}


public Workout(String name, String MG, String male, String num1, String num2, String t,String num3, String time, String workout2) {

    this.name = name;
    this.MG = MG;
    this.male = male;
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.t = t;
    this.num3 = num3;
    this.time = time;


}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMG() {
    return MG;
}

public void setMG(String MG) {
    this.MG = MG;
}

public String getMale() {
    return male;
}

public void setMale(String male) {
    this.male = male;
}

public String getNum1() {
    return num1;
}

public void setNum1(String num1) {
    this.num1 = num1;
}

public String getNum2() {
    return num2;
}

public void setNum2(String num2) {
    this.num2 = num2;
}

public String getT() {
    return t;
}

public void setT(String t) {
    this.t = t;
}

public String getNum3() {
    return num3;
}

public void setNum3(String num3) {
    this.num3 = num3;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = name + '\n' +
            MG +"  "+  male +"  "+ t +"\n"+
            time + "\n"+
            num1 + "\n"+
            num2 +"\n"+
            num3;


    for(Note note : workout2)
    {
        str += note +" ";
    }

    return str;
}
```

}

Код в папке Note:

```
public class Note{

public String value;

public Note(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Note() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
}
```

}

Если смотреть по Debug, и у меня появляется ошибка при добавлении данных в ListA(До этого все проходит):

```
listA.add(workout);
```

Как решить эту проблему?))))

Logcat ошибка:

```
12-13 17:43:20.787 23124-23124/com.example.monsterfitness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.monsterfitness, PID: 23124
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:251)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:177)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:604)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.example.monsterfitness.wods$1.onDataChange(wods.java:38)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Вариантов ошибки может быть несколько сотен. Чтобы все перечислить - нужны часы набора текста. И дни, чтобы расписать варианты решения проблем для каждого варианта ошибки. А вот если вы расскажете что за ошибка у вас (это можно в логах посмотреть), то, скорее всего, ошибка будет одна и описание решения проблемы займёт пару минут.

Comment: `List<Note> workout2` -> `Map<String, Note> workout2`